# How to upgrade SWM 8802 to Android 8.1

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, 8.1-oreo, android-sdk, android-auto

I purchased a SWM 8802 double din automotive head unit from ebay and I was under the impression that it would have android 7.1 installed as advertised. Turns out it actually has android 5.1, which has a tonne of limitations. I found a few forums online that contain some updates, but many members have bricked or bootlooped their units.

https://forum.xda-developers.com/android-auto/android-auto-general/failure-swm8802-t3750908/page4

https://www.needrom.com/download/swm-8802/

I am wondering if anyone has been able to successfully update the SWM 8802 headunit to android 8.1 and if so, what is the exact process?

More specifically I have a couple issues I need to resolve:

**Bluetooth** - I cannot connect to my OBDII bluetooth device or control any bluetooth settings as there are no options for this.

**Touch Beep** - The head unit beeps every time I touch it and there are no settings to disable it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Not likely... The OEM's of these head units, especially the "cheap Chinese ones" (no offense to anyone) often do not release kernel source code or OS upgrades, , which are almost essential to 3rd party ROM development, and updates are often only issued for critical issues. Android is not "generic" and must be built specifically for each device, without the kernel source this is almost impossible. If the OEM hasn't followed the Android GPL license and released the kernel source code, which happens often with "generic" low dollar products, these are often just considered disposable products.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. Seems like I don't have many options but to find some work arounds.